# CSS Float for images does not work correctly

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a website with three pictures that would be at the right side of the screen, while having some text at the left side of it. The problem is, even though I have set `float:right;` correctly, the text is pushing the images down.

```css
body {
  background: #1a0000;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: #b30000;
}

.txt {
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  border-top: 10px solid #b30000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #b30000;
}

.floatleft {
  display: :block;
  float: left;
}

.floatright {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.clanok {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.txt {
  text-align: left;
}

article :first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sd {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both;
  border: 5px solid #b30000;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.sd img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

<head>
  <title>Dota 2 demonology</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="dota2.png" class="floatleft">
    <h1>Demonologia v Doto2</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="clanok">
    <article>
      <p>
        Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
        text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text
      </p>

      <aside class="sd floatright">
        <q>
     <img src="sd.jpg">
     Shadow Demon <br>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </q>
      </aside>

      <aside class="sd floatright">
        <q>
     <img src="sf.png">
     Shadow Fiend <br>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </q>
      </aside>

      <aside class="sd floatright">
        <q>
     <img src="doom.jpg">
     Doom <br>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </q>
      </aside>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The text is before the image in your source, so it has already "claimed" the full width of the page before your floated image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first p shall be `width: 45%;` (in this case! usually it has to be 100% minus whatever is on the other side) and `float: left;` then remove `clear: both;` from `.sd`

```css
body {
 background: #1a0000;
 padding: 10px;
}

img {
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
}

h1 {
 padding-top: 30px;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 color: #b30000;
}

.txt {
 padding: 0;
}

.logo {
 border-top: 10px solid #b30000;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #b30000;
}

.floatleft {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.floatright {
 display: block;
 float: right;
}

.clanok {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.txt {
 text-align: left;
}

article :first-child {
 font-size: 20px;
}
.first-p {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}

.sd {
 float: right;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border: 5px solid #b30000;
 max-width: 300px;
 max-height: 400px;
 overflow: scroll;
}

.sd img {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<head>
 <title>Dota 2 demonology</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="logo">  
 <img src="dota2.png" class="floatleft">
 <h1>Demonologia v Doto2</h1>
 </div>
  
  <div class="clanok">
   <article>
    <p class="first-p">
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </p>
    
    <aside class="sd floatright">
    <q>
     <img src="sd.jpg">
     Shadow Demon <br>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </q>
    </aside>

    <aside class="sd floatright">
    <q>
     <img src="sf.png">
     Shadow Fiend <br>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </q>
    </aside>

    <aside class="sd floatright">
    <q>
     <img src="doom.jpg">
     Doom <br>
     Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
    </q>
    </aside>
   </article>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your CSS. You've written the colon twice. Correcting that should fix it.

```
display: :block;
```